# Установка symfony2

Tags: cmd, фреймворк, php, symfony2

Здравствуйте, как говориться первый блин всегда комом.

Не могу установить symfony2 sandbox , пытаюсь по  [мануалу](http://habrahabr.ru/post/51921/) 
Дошел до это стройки 
**$ php symfony propel:build-model** 
которую нужно вести через командную строку, но перед этим нужно обратится к php как я понял, раньше через командную строку я не обращался, знаю только как запустить ну и пару функций cd итд,  не хочу гадать и тратить на это время, кто знает подскажите пожалуйста. 
Платформа для веб разработки используется Open server. Могу установить денвер если надо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony не использовал, но что-то вы перемудрили. Сейчас поставил без **устаревших(!)** мануалов.

1. Используете OpenServer - и правильно. Только версию PHP выберите 5.3.*
2. Создаете, к примеру домен **symfony.loc**
3. В корне какую-нибудь папку, напр., **my_symfony**
4. Распаковали [архив последней версии](http://symfony.com/download?v=Symfony_Standard_Vendors_2.1.0.zip) в эту папку.
5. Проверяем, запустив http://symfony.loc/my_symfony/web/app_dev.php

Если видим такую картинку, как ниже, то всё гуд ;)

[image]